# Drag&drop animation optimization in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, drag-and-drop, core-animation, catransform3d

I added a lot of animations and all of them are performed via transform property (Core Animation, `CATransform3D`). The problem is I need to recalculate all the transforms for each object in scene starting from zero because drag&drop may have influence on all the objects (and this influence should be animated too).

Any ideas how to improve the performance on drag&drop? For example:

http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncE/XEE/ncEXEEjpi.jpeg

The square is moved on long press gesture. And its scale depends on its `center.x` value. Is it possible to calculate and apple the transformation one time/cache for dragging? Or should I use something else, not Core Animation?

**EDITED**

I use the following project as prototype for drag&drop:

https://github.com/heikomaass/HMLauncherView

From its code:

```
- (void) didLongPressIcon:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) sender {
    if ([self.scrollView isDragging]) {
        return;
    }
    HMLauncherIcon *icon = (HMLauncherIcon*) sender.view;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (self.dragIcon == nil) {
            [self longPressBegan:icon];
        }
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint iconPoint = [sender locationInView:self];
        if (self.dragIcon == icon) {

//Recalculate transform
            [self longPressMoved:icon toPoint:iconPoint];
        }
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (self.dragIcon == icon) {

//Recalculate transform
            [self longPressEnded:icon ];
        }
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
        if (self.dragIcon == icon) {

//Recalculate transform
            [self longPressEnded:icon];
        }
    }
}
```

"Recalculate transform" means something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:... animations:^{

    for (UIView *oneIcon in self.icons) {
        CATransform3D transform = ...;//some calculations with icon.center.x
        CGAffineTransform affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(transform);
        oneIcon.transform = affineTransform;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to know how your code might be improved if you don't show it.

Comment: edited question. I hope now its is more clear for you

Comment: Are you having a performance problem or code complexity problem?

Comment: Performance problem because of complex calculations. It seems it had been ok before I added 3D transformations.